# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'da'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I keep getting the same ValueError for the following code and I am having a hard time understanding why the error is being generated.  It is my understanding that this error is generated when the wrong value is passed into a function, however, I do not really understand what this error is telling me.  I've spent time searching online and in the docs, but I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong.  Simply, why is this error being generated?

My code:

```
import datetime
import ystockquote

def new_time(n):
    fmt = "%Y%m%d"
    end_date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(n, fmt)
    sixty_day = datetime.timedelta(days=60)
    start_date  = end_date1 - sixty_day
    start_date1 = str(start_date)
    start_date2 = start_date1[:4] + start_date1[5:7] + start_date1[8:10]
    return start_date2

def average_atr():
    print "Enter your stock symbol: "
    symbol      = raw_input(" ")
    print "Enter the end date in (YYYYMMDD) format: "
    end_date    = raw_input(" ")
    start_date  = new_time(end_date)
    initial_list = ystockquote.get_historical_prices('symbol', 'start_date', 'end_date')

def start():
    average_atr()

start()
```

This is the relevant code for ystockquote:

```
def get_historical_prices(symbol, start_date, end_date):
    """
    Get historical prices for the given ticker symbol.
    Date format is 'YYYYMMDD'

    Returns a nested list.
    """
    url = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s&' % symbol + \
          'd=%s&' % str(int(end_date[4:6]) - 1) + \
          'e=%s&' % str(int(end_date[6:8])) + \
          'f=%s&' % str(int(end_date[0:4])) + \
          'g=d&' + \
          'a=%s&' % str(int(start_date[4:6]) - 1) + \
          'b=%s&' % str(int(start_date[6:8])) + \
          'c=%s&' % str(int(start_date[0:4])) + \
          'ignore=.csv'
    days = urllib.urlopen(url).readlines()
    data = [day[:-2].split(',') for day in days]
    return data
```

Please note that the ystockquote code above is not the complete code.

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: The error means that you're trying to call `int('da')`, i.e. either `start_date` or `end_date` is in the wrong format. Try printing them out or running in `pdb` to see what they actually are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the function `average_atr()`, change the following line:

```
initial_list = ystockquote.get_historical_prices('symbol', 'start_date', 'end_date')
```

to:

```
initial_list = ystockquote.get_historical_prices(symbol, start_date, end_date)
```

In your current version, instead of passing the variables into `ystockquote.get_historical_prices()`, you are passing literal strings with the variable names.  This is resulting in `str(int(end_date[4:6]) - 1)` with the variable `end_date` having the value `'end_date'`, and `'end_date'[4:6]` is `'da'`.

Comment: Thank you.  I feel like a putz, but it's working now.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending strings 'start_date' and 'end_date' into the function get_historical_prices.
It appears that function was expecting actual string-date values to be passed in instead. Just remove the quotes around the arguments in this line:

```
initial_list = ystockquote.get_historical_prices('symbol', 'start_date', 'end_date')
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have noticed that.